# How to in Jssor full width + height by window size

Tags: javascript, css, slider, jssor

I would like to have fixed height by window height + full width.
For example picture of size 2600x1800.
Window size is 950x450.

I call `ScaleSlider()` function and inside:

1. When I use `$ScaleWidth(width)` height is 1800.
2. When I use `$ScaleHeight(height)` then height is OK, but width is scaled to cca 800.

I used config param $FillMode: from 0 to 5, but not expected result.

I don't need aspect ratio or scale. For me is ok, that height of image will be like cutted.

It works as expected when I harcoded IMG tag with: `object-fit: cover;width: 100%;height: 100%;` and then up to everything to 100%, then parent class slider_container set to `transform: scale(1); height: 450px`. After resize browser everything is broken again.

How to do it with jssor please?

Comment: We are looking for full window solution. Hope we can get it ready soon. For now, as workaround, please take reference of the 2 full window example in the development pack.

Comment: Full width worx well without workaround, but not as described functionality.
Just height must be always by window height. Here is example how it worx well. http://demo.coderspoint.net/web-bean/bizniz2/

Comment: I think you are looking for `examples/full-screen-cover-window.html`. It is in the download package https://github.com/jssor/slider/archive/master.zip

Comment: 1.
No same. You dont understand this problem. See my example template.

2.
Try described jssor example example yourself and you will see that its not same.
When I add few lines: <p>o</p> before end tag body, your example is impossible to scroll down. When I resizing browser, Image in your example is not changed  like my example template.

Comment: Wow, very good question, thanks a lot! Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New Full Screen Example**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <title>Full Screen Slider - Jssor Slider</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                /*position: fixed;*/
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head> 
    <body style="font-family: Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif;">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.slider-25.0.6.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            jssor_slider1_init = function () {

                var options = {
                    $AutoPlay: 0,                                       //[Optional] Auto play or not, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to greater than 0. Default value is 0. 0: no auto play, 1: continuously, 2: stop at last slide, 4: stop on click, 8: stop on user navigation (by arrow/bullet/thumbnail/drag/arrow key navigation)
                    $Idle: 1500,                                        //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                    $PauseOnHover: 1,                                   //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1
                    $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $Cols is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
                    $ArrowKeyNavigation: 1,                             //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request by pressing arrow key, default value is 1.
                    $SlideDuration: 800,                                //Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds

                    $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                           //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                        $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,                  //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                        $ChanceToShow: 2                                //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    }
                };

                var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
                //responsive code begin
                //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing
                function ScaleSlider() {
                    var parentNode = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode;
                    var parentWidth = parentNode.clientWidth;
                    if (parentWidth) {
                        var parentHeight = parentNode.clientHeight;
                        jssor_slider1.$ScaleSize(parentWidth, parentHeight);
                    }
                    else {
                        $Jssor$.$Delay(ScaleSlider, 30);
                    }
                }

                ScaleSlider();

                $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
                $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
                $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
                //responsive code end
            };
        </script>

        <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
        <div style="position:relative;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;">
            <div id="slider1_container" style="margin: 0 auto; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 800px;
                height: 356px; background: #191919; overflow: hidden;">

                <!-- Loading Screen -->
                <div data-u="loading" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;background:url('../img/loading.gif') no-repeat 50% 50%; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);"></div>

                <!-- Slides Container -->
                <div data-u="slides" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 800px; height: 356px; overflow: hidden;">
                    <div>
                        <img u="image" src="../img/alila/01.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img u="image" src="../img/alila/02.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img u="image" src="../img/alila/03.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img u="image" src="../img/alila/04.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img u="image" src="../img/alila/05.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img u="image" src="../img/alila/06.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img u="image" src="../img/alila/07.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img u="image" src="../img/alila/08.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img u="image" src="../img/alila/09.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img u="image" src="../img/alila/10.jpg" />
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <img u="image" src="../img/alila/11.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img u="image" src="../img/alila/12.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--#region Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
                <style>
                    /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 05 css */
                    /*
                    .jssora05l                  (normal)
                    .jssora05r                  (normal)
                    .jssora05l:hover            (normal mouseover)
                    .jssora05r:hover            (normal mouseover)
                    .jssora05l.jssora05ldn      (mousedown)
                    .jssora05r.jssora05rdn      (mousedown)
                    .jssora05l.jssora05lds      (disabled)
                    .jssora05r.jssora05rds      (disabled)
                    */
                    .jssora05l, .jssora05r {
                        display: block;
                        position: absolute;
                        /* size of arrow element */
                        width: 40px;
                        height: 40px;
                        cursor: pointer;
                        background: url(../img/a17.png) no-repeat;
                        overflow: hidden;
                    }
                    .jssora05l { background-position: -10px -40px; }
                    .jssora05r { background-position: -70px -40px; }
                    .jssora05l:hover { background-position: -130px -40px; }
                    .jssora05r:hover { background-position: -190px -40px; }
                    .jssora05l.jssora05ldn { background-position: -250px -40px; }
                    .jssora05r.jssora05rdn { background-position: -310px -40px; }

                    .jssora05l.jssora05lds { background-position: -10px -40px; opacity: .3; pointer-events: none; }
                    .jssora05r.jssora05rds { background-position: -70px -40px; opacity: .3; pointer-events: none; }
                </style>
                <!-- Arrow Left -->
                <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="top: 158px; left: 8px;">
                </span>
                <!-- Arrow Right -->
                <span u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="top: 158px; right: 8px">
                </span>
                <!--#endregion Arrow Navigator Skin End -->

                <!-- Trigger -->
                <script>
                    jssor_slider1_init();
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Jssor Slider End -->

        <!-- remove the following if no need-->
        <p>other content</p>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: This test looks good but after some tests I see some problems. Arrows a Bullets top position is bad calculated when image is very height.

Comment: Please see updated answer, in this example, we use new api `$ScaleSize`.

Comment: You are right. We are working on it. We will publish version 25.0.0 soon. And now it's available here `https://www.jssor.com/script*`.

Comment: With this last Jsson I got jQuery error : Uncaught ReferenceError: $JssorEasing$ is not defined

Comment: Now I see that JssorEasing is not exists any more in Jssor and I changed to $Jease$ only, the same with $CaptionTransitions -> $Transitions. Ohh. 
Now I see Arrows with Jssor 25.x.x but not bullets. But full width is now broken.

Comment: Right, $JssorEasing$ is for backward compatibility, it is the same as $Jease$. To reduce the js library size, we will remove it since 25.0.0.

Comment: `$CaptionTransitions` changed to `$Transitions` since version 20 I think.

Comment: Full width works ok at my end, can you send me your full width demo?

Comment: No, it doesnt, you dont read history. 
Slides are OK, but missing arrows and bullets, caption animation not work. You can check in inline JS my configuration.

Comment: I just checked your demo, the caption transition format is wrong. You can use jssor slider maker to generate transitions. For arrows, I will double check your demo before we publish 25 (in a few days).

Comment: hi there, i checked your demo here, please use the code in the updated answer. Also, please use jssor.slider.25.0.6.min.js for full screen slider.

Comment: Seems it works as expected. On my localhost i see that image is visible in full size and after jssor is initialized it is resized to wight size. On public domain it is soo fast and impossible to see it.
I have another question, if anywhere exists all predefined animations list of configurations. I dont want to build each definition at your online tool.

Comment: if anywhere exists all predefined caption animations. As is for all transitions https://www.jssor.com/help/slideshow-transitions.html I dont want to build each definition at your online tool.

Comment: I can not find any info about what is wrong in my cartion transition:
var _CaptionTransitions=[];_CaptionTransitions = [{$Duration:1200,x:0.6,$Zoom:3,$Rotate:-0.3,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$EaseInCubic,$Rotate:$Jease$.$EaseInBack},$Opacity:2}];

Comment: In jssor.min.js 24.1.3 I can see EaseInOutSine for example, but not in 25.0.6. Do you have some conversion table how to change old caption transion to new ones?

Comment: `JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine` equals `$Jease$.$InOutSine`. Please replace `$JssorEasing$.$Ease` with `$Jease$.$`.

Comment: Caption slider changed to caption slideo 2 years ago, the layer animates with one or more transitions in timeline. a layer has an array of transitions. It's very hard to write transition code manually, you'd better use slider maker  to build transitions.

Comment: I already said that it is impossible do it via your tool. I already have cca 500 caption transitions which worked well before and now not. Its problem of all open source projects which changes basic thinkgs. I need some conversion tool or conversion manual. Other way is unacceptable.

Comment: Or just publish some information about BEFORE and AFTER. Or normal changelog.